# Installing a Remote Event Receiver on "Site Pages" library using BaseTemplate ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, remote-event-receiver, sitepages

I need my Remote Event Receiver to install to the "Site Pages" library without referencing the Title/name, but rather use the ID (119) or GUID. I can't use title because the support for multiple languages.

I have tried a couple different things, but get ***ClientRequestException***.

```
public void InstallRER(ClientContext ctx)
    {   Guid g = new Guid("00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18");
        ctx.Load(ctx.Web.Lists, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, list => list.EventReceivers).Where(list => list.BaseTemplate.Equals("119")));
        ctx.Load(ctx.Web.Lists, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, list => list.EventReceivers).Where(list => list.BaseTemplate.Equals(119)));
        ctx.Load(ctx.Web.Lists, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, list => list.EventReceivers).Where(list => list.TemplateFeatureId.Equals(119)));
        ctx.Load(ctx.Web.Lists, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, list => list.EventReceivers).Where(list => list.BaseTemplate.Equals(ListTemplateType.WebPageLibrary)));
        ctx.Load(ctx.Web.Lists, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, list => list.EventReceivers).Where(list => list.TemplateFeatureId.Equals(g)));
        ctx.Load(ctx.Web.Lists, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, list => list.EventReceivers).Where(list => list.BaseType.Equals("WebPageLibrary")));
        ctx.Load(ctx.Web.Lists, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, list => list.EventReceivers).Where(list => list.BaseType.Equals((int)ListTemplateType.WebPageLibrary)));
        ctx.Load(ctx.Web.Lists, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, list => list.EventReceivers).Where(list => list.BaseType.Equals("DocumentLibrary") && (list.BaseTemplate.Equals(119))));
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        List SitePageList = ctx.Web.Lists.FirstOrDefault();
        EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation CheckedIn = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation();
        CheckedIn.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemCheckedIn;
        OperationContext op = OperationContext.Current;
        Message m = op.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
        CheckedIn.ReceiverUrl = m.Headers.To.ToString();
        CheckedIn.ReceiverName = name;
        CheckedIn.Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;
        SitePageList.EventReceivers.Add(CheckedIn);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

***Appreciate any help I can get!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this( the error caused by Equal in Linq based on my testing).

```
Guid g = new Guid("00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18");
                context.Load(context.Web.Lists, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, list => list.EventReceivers).Where(l => l.TemplateFeatureId == g));
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                List SitePageList = context.Web.Lists.FirstOrDefault();
```